# Save Listview to Settings

Tags: vb.net, listview, settings

I'm trying to save my listview content to my.settings.aangemeld

My listview contains 2 columns.

What's the best way to do this??

I'm using visual basic 2010 :)

Comment: What flavor of code are you using: VB? C#?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add a button and change the buttons Text to Save, then Add this code

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    For count As Integer = 1 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        My.Settings.Bookmarks.Add(ListView1.Items(count).ToString)

    Next
    Try
```

My.Settings.Save()

```
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```